# Package Node-Red using zeit/pkg

Tags: node.js, packaging, node-red, zeit-pkg

I am having some issues using [zeit/pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) on my node-red project. Here are the steps to replicate the issue:

1. `git clone https://github.com/node-red/node-red.git`
2. `cd node-red`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run build`
5. After build command I added the following to my package.json file:

   ```
   "pkg": {
      "assets": [
         "./red/**/*"
      ],
      "scripts": [
         "./red/**/*.js"
      ]
   }
   ```
6. Run the command `pkg .`

After running `pkg .` I get the following errors:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\node-red>pkg .
> pkg@4.3.4
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node8-linux-x64, node8-macos-x64, node8-win-x64
> Warning Cannot resolve 'path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'package.json')'
  C:\xampp\htdocs\node-red\red\runtime\index.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
> Warning Cannot resolve ''./' + aSettings.storageModule'
  C:\xampp\htdocs\node-red\red\runtime\storage\index.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
> Warning Cannot resolve 'relPath'
  C:\xampp\htdocs\node-red\red\runtime\nodes\registry\loader.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
```

Running the exe after the pkg command gives me this error:
`Node-RED has not been built. See README.md for details`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems like a simple path issue but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: You not actually stated what the problem is here. The packaging step shows a bunch of warnings, but you've not said what happens if you try and run it after packaging

Comment: When I run the exe it says "Node-RED has not been built." and exits.

Comment: I have never used zeit/pkg but I am wondering if the problem is not with the installation of node-red.  I have never installed Node-RED that way so I can not immediately say.  Did you try to start node-RED and checked that you could connect to the node-RED editor using <node-red-ip-address>:1880  ?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation.html#for-development---from-github

Comment: If you want to package node-red in windows. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2wiA0F9vPo